# Showing a variant number of images stored in database with html

Tags: php, html, image

I have my images stored in a certain path inside my server. In my database I keep the name they are stored with and several other information but **NOT THE ACTUAL IMAGE**. I can display them with `IMG src="...."` using the path and the name but what I actually want is to somehow display **ALL** of them. The problem is that the number of images will not be always the same because the users in the site I'm making can add and delete them any-time they want. So without knowing the exact number I can't write `IMG src="....."` as many times I have to. What can I do for that?

I hope I made myself clear about my question.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? I'd recommend you to query all the images you need in your database and then a loop printing `<img>` tags.

Comment: @asurbernardo This is what I have in mind but I am quite new to this and have no clue how to loop <img> tags or any tag generally. I can loop inside php but how can I affect the html tags with it?Could you show me a code that would create many <img> tags?

Comment: Yes sure but since I don't have the code it might be really generic

Comment: You may put the `<img>` tag in a `for` loop.

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving any code but I don't know which part of my code would help cause this is more like a general question. @NitishKumar Can I do a for loop in the php and echo <img src = "C\\xampp\\....\\image1.jpg"> and change the last part depending on the name?If I put this in <body> tag will it display the images?

Comment: It can work. Giving your code will be useful to give the exact solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a little bit confused, PHP is a server language but it can print HTML simply using methods like `echo`, so you just need to query those images you need and do the following:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// Query the images, add the condition you want adding a WHERE clause
$sql="SELECT * FROM images";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$images = array();
// Now you store the images you in an array, so you can use them anywhere
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $images[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now you have the images stored in the `$images` array, so you can print them anywhere you want like this:

```
<?php 
   foreach ($images as $image) { 
       echo "<img src=".$image['path_to_the_image']."></img>";
   }
?>
```

Foreach loop will handle the amount of images you have, so don't worry about the number.

This [page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp) will be useful if you still don't understand how php can interact with HTML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @asubernardo Thank you so much for your time and your answer!If I understand correct you echo the exact string you would write manually!!I managed to do what I had in mind as an excercise but at my site I need a php variable in the path.Now another issue came up to me when I tried using php inside it.For example :
for($i=0;$i<images.length;i++){
    echo" <IMG src=\"images/<?php echo $img;?>\"/>
}
Is php placing html wich calls php a bit too much?

Comment: @Aris13 That code in your comment is wrong, that for should be already inside `<?php ?>` tags so you can't reopen them again in `<?php echo $img;?>`, you just use `$img` get rid of those tags and the echo because you are already echoing:   `echo "<IMG src='images/$img' /> ";`

Comment: @asubernardo Works perfect!! Once again thank you for your response!!Thank you so much :)!!

Comment: @Aris13 Glad to hear that! If this is solved just mark the answer as valid so other people with your problem can find it. Happy coding!